# create multiple lists in a single page in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-enterprise

First sorry about my English.
I have a question regarding to view a multiple view in one single page.. is it something that can be done in sharepoint 2010?
Or is it possible to achieve...
for example I have 3 lists: list1, list2 and list3. Each lists has different columns to each other, however all the lists have 2 of

the same columns which are Year and week. So it is possible to create an expandable view like this

Year 2013 (all list has this column) 
     * week 3 (all list has this column) 
          *list1 (with the rest of the column) 
          *list2 (with the rest of the column) 
          *list3 (with the rest of the column) 
     *week 2 
     *week 1 
Year 2012 
     *week 52 
     *week 51

Many thanks in advance guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you added multiple content types to the same list you could achieve this in a standard list view web part.

If that is not an option then you could maybe use SharePoint Designer to establish a combined data source from all 3 lists.

Depending on where the lists are you could potentially use a CQWP and customise the XSL.

The only other way I can think of is to add all 3 lists to the page, use jQuery to grab the contents of all of them into an array and then lay out your view using the jQuery.

Comment: cool.. thanks for your advise.. works just great with multiple content types

Comment: Well done!  Glad it worked :)